# How to click on the button to change its properties and disable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Please help me.
There is a button:

```
<v-btn dark color="primary" class="square">Tile 1</v-btn>
```

How to make it so that after a click to change it to flat, disable it and change its color, for example - white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a property called `isFlatten` to you data object like :

```
data(){
   return{
         isFlatten:false
      }
 }
```

and in your template do :

`<v-btn dark color="primary" class="square" :flat="isFlatten" @click="isFlatten=true">Tile 1</v-btn>`